# How to prepend a string to a column value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need a SQL update statement for updating a particular field of all the rows with a string "test" to be added in the front of the existing value.

For example, if the existing value is "try" it should become "testtry".

Answer (score 298, accepted):

You can use the [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to do that:

```
UPDATE tbl SET col=CONCAT('test',col);
```

If you want to get cleverer and only update columns which don't already have test prepended, try

```
UPDATE tbl SET col=CONCAT('test',col)
WHERE col NOT LIKE 'test%';
```

Answer (score 18):

```
UPDATE tablename SET fieldname = CONCAT("test", fieldname) [WHERE ...]
```

Comment: update TICKET set status_details = CONCAT(status _details,'abc') where ticket_id=75108;
ERROR 1583 (42000): Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'CONCAT'

Answer (score 13):

Many string update functions in MySQL seems to be working like this:
If one argument is `null`, then concatenation or other functions return `null` too.
So, to update a field with `null` value, first set it to a non-null value, such as `''`

For example:

```
update table set field='' where field is null;
update table set field=concat(field,' append');
```

Answer (score 7):

That's a simple one

```
UPDATE YourTable SET YourColumn = CONCAT('prependedString', YourColumn);
```

Comment: Correct up to the WHERE clause, where you only concat test to columns already starting with test.

So:
foo -> foo
footest -> footest
testfoo -> testtestfoo

Answer (score 1):

- UPDATE table_name SET Column1 = CONCAT('newtring', table_name.Column1) where 1
- UPDATE table_name SET Column1 = CONCAT('newtring', table_name.Column2) where 1
- UPDATE table_name SET Column1 = CONCAT('newtring', table_name.Column2, 'newtring2') where 1

We can concat same column or also other column of the table.