# Appending data to a MySQL database field that already has data in it

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I need to "add" data to a field that already contains data without erasing whats currently there.  For example if the field contains HTML, I need to add additional HTML to the field.   Is there a SQL call that will do this or do I need to call the data in that field, concatenate the new data to the existing data, and reload it into the database?

Comment: almost duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680801/how-to-prepend-a-string-to-a-column-value-in-mysql - it is about prepending

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table SET Field=CONCAT(Field,'your extra html');
```

Comment: nice one really awesome.

Answer (score 12):

```
UPDATE myTable SET html=concat(html,'<b>More HTML</b>') WHERE id='10'
```

... for example.  Your WHERE would be different of course.

Answer (score 4):

Append at the end of a field, separated with with a line break:

```
UPDATE Table SET Comment = CONCAT_WS(CHAR(10 USING UTF8), Comment, 'my comment.');
```

- [`CONCAT_WS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) appends multiple strings separated by a given separator.
- `CHAR(10, UTF8)` is a line break.

Answer (score 4):

`UPDATE Table SET Field=CONCAT(IFNULL(Field, ''), 'Your extra HTML')`

If the field contains NULL value then CONCAT will also return NULL. Using IFNULL will help you to update column even it has NULL value.

Comment: This instruction appends to all rows. If you want to append only in one specific row add this at the end of the expression: `WHERE your_row = $your_var`.