# How can I append a string to an existing field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, append

I want to update the code on all my record to what they currently are plus _standard any ideas?

So for example if the codes are apple_1 and apple_2 I need them to be apple_1_standard and apple_2_standard

### Before:

```
id   code
------------
1    apple_1 
1    apple_2
```

### Psuedo Query:

```
update categories set code = code + "_standard" where id = 1;
```

### Expected result:

```
id   code
----------------------
1    apple_1_standard 
1    apple_2_standard
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761583/appending-data-to-a-mysql-database-field-that-already-has-data-in-it

Answer (score 311, accepted):

You need to use the [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function in MySQL for string concatenation:

```
UPDATE categories SET code = CONCAT(code, '_standard') WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: Just in case somebody runs into the same issue as I did: If the field `code` is NULL by default you need to use: `UPDATE categories SET code = CONCAT(IFNULL(code,''), '_standard') WHERE id = 1;` Otherwise the concat will always result in NULL.

Comment: Alternatively you can use CONCAT_WS which skips NULL values. For example `SELECT CONCAT_WS(', ','First name',NULL,'Last Name');`
        gives  'First name, Last Name'

Comment: @Daniel How about updating the answer according to comments above?

Comment: special/separate question for possible null case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020867/mysql-update-append-data-into-column

Answer (score 15):

Update image field to add full URL, ignoring null fields:

```
UPDATE test SET image = CONCAT('https://my-site.com/images/',image) WHERE image IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Whats funny is even though this doesn't answer the OP question very well, this is exactly what I needed.