# MySQL UPDATE append data into column

Tags: mysql, append, sql-update

I need to UPDATE tablename (col1name)

If there is already data, I need to append it with values 'a,b,c'
If it is NULL, I need to add the values 'a,b,c'

I know there is a CONCAT argument, but not sure what the SQL syntax would be.

`update tablename set col1name = concat(ifnull(col1name, 'a,b,c'), 'a,b,c')`

Is the above correct?

Comment: @FahimParkar I didn't realize I could have used SQL Fiddle, but did not wish to try something uncertain on a live website. Thank you.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Try this Query:

```
update tablename set col1name = concat(ifnull(col1name,""), 'a,b,c');
```

[Refer this sql fiddle demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62cff)

Comment: SQL fiddle demo outputs error for me (both in FF and Chrome). Created another one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8385a3/1/0

Answer (score 10):

This should do it:

```
update tablename set
col1name = if(col1name is null, 'a,b,c', concat(col1name, 'a,b,c'));
```

Or you could make your life easier by doing it in two steps:

```
update tablename set col1name = '' where col1name is null;
```

then

```
update tablename set col1name = concat(col1name, 'a,b,c');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following:

```
update yourtable 
set yourcol = case when yourcol is null then 'a,b,c'
                  else concat(yourcol, ' a,b,c') end
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d530e/1)

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable(`yourcol` varchar(50));

INSERT INTO yourtable(`yourcol`)
VALUES  ('sadsdh'),
    (NULL);
```

Will return:

```
|      YOURCOL |
----------------
| sadsdh a,b,c |
|        a,b,c |
```

Answer (score 0):

IFNULL(column,''), saves any if statements, makes the SQL much simpler!

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename
    (`yourcol` varchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO tablename
    (`yourcol`)
VALUES
    ('sadsdh'),
    (NULL)
;

UPDATE tablename SET
    yourcol = CONCAT( IFNULL(yourcol,' '), 'somevalue' )
;
```

**[Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d6b6/1)**:

```
select *
from tablename
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d6b6/1/0)**:

```
|         yourcol |
|-----------------|
| sadsdhsomevalue |
|       somevalue |
```

Answer (score 0):

For those requiring a prepared-statement option, this example may help:

```
update tablename set col1name = concat(ifnull(col1name,""), ?) WHERE table_id = ?;
```

Regular binding will work; in this case two variables: **col1name** and **table_id**. This could be handy in change/upate logs. No need of grabbing previous logs.

Answer (score -1):

why are you write ifnull function: it is obvious that if col1name1 is empty it concatenate to null means null+'a,b,c' simply 'a,b,c'
set col1name = concat(ifnull(col1name,""), 'a,b,c')
instead of this you can directly write
set col1name = concat(col1name, 'a,b,c')