# How to append a value to an existing column in mysql which can contain null or a String?

Tags: mysql

in my table a column selected contains default value null, but i want to update the column by appending a string to it with a condition that **if the field contains null then it should be updated** else if it contains any other string then i need to update it like **update tabname set colname=concat(colname,',newString')**? any information would be a great help for me thanks in advance...

Comment: *if the field contains null then it should be updated* what will be added to your column in this case ?

Comment: in that case the query will be update tabname set colname='newString' @MKhalidJunaid

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020867/mysql-update-append-data-into-column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `case`

```
 update tabname
 set colname= case when colname is null or colname =''
              then 'newString'
              else concat(colname,'newString')
              end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot perfectly matched for my requirement once again thank you very much. @M Khalid Junaid