# How to append data in a mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, append

Please don't mark this as a duplicate since I have already read the following post but still can't understand this issue:

[MySQL UPDATE append data into column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020867/mysql-update-append-data-into-column)

I want to append data when users post multiple times. I have a ecommerce site. Now, if the user wants to upload several products for sale, I can't store the information. how would I go about this? should I use UPDATE syntax plus a .= or should I use INSERT plus .= ? I have tried INSERT on my query but it doesn't append anything. and update just replaces the existing data with the new one.

please help me as I like to learn.

here is my code for query:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO user(user_id, post_title, post_description) Values('{$user}', '{$productname}', '{$post_desc}')");     
 $sql .= $conn->query("INSERT INTO user(user_id, post_title, post_description) Values('{$user}', '{$productname}', '{$post_desc}')");     
    // or should I use the below update query?
 $sql .= $conn->query("UPDATE user SET post_title = '{$productname}', post_description = '{$post_desc}' WHERE user_id=$user");
```

}

Comment: seriously did you really had to give it a -1? like if I am trying to waste the communities time? Oh my God.

Comment: Can you provide us with some code please?

Comment: @xElsa sure one sec please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Whomever gave me a +1 thank you. However, I promise to learn how to ask questions here. but I am a newbie. So sorry.

Comment: which column are you wanting to append?

Comment: @user5200287 all of them. the purpose of this is for users to be able to post as many times as they like. so a product should have a description about it and a title but I think I should take out the user_id though.

Comment: instead of appending just add a new row for each post

Comment: @user5200287 can you please give me a hint as far as how to do that? my theory was that I have to do something like this:  $sql .= UPDATE but that only replaced the information in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add a new row for each post:

```
$sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO user(user_id, post_title, post_description) Values('$user', '$productname', '$post_desc')");
```

Comment: I have already tried this but it wouldn't add a new row.

Comment: well it should so try adding `echo $conn->error;` after querying to see if there is an error.

Comment: i did ask for the error and I got this: Duplicate entry '4' for key 'PRIMARY' what does this mean? thanks.

Comment: that shouldn't be the problem but you can change the variable name just in case. but are you getting an error from what I just commented?

Comment: I think I know what it means. this is saying that you can't insert twice in the same field but my problem is that I need to create a new row for the same user but it wouldn't.

Comment: I see your problem. you need to add another column to the table and name it id and set it as primary and set it to auto increment. that should fix it

Comment: yes my friend. and it seems like its not wanting to add a new row for the same user. it treats my query as a one time deal for each user.

Comment: well, user_id is a foreign key referencing user_id in the users table. which is the parent table. so you think even though this is a foreign key, I can still set it as primary? by the way I just looked at it and it is auto incrementing even in the child table.

Comment: thats probably because the user_id column is set as primary and so you can't duplicate it. that's why you need to create a separate column and set it as the primary.

Comment: your right user_id is set as primary key in both tables so do you recommend me to delete it and set another column and then set that column as primary. and mean while reset the user_id column in the child table but referrence it to parent table?

Comment: you don't have to delete user_id just add a new column and set the new column as primary and auto increment. done.

Comment: user5200287 thanks buddy this solved my problem.