# I want to insert a value multiple time in a same field without disturbing the previous data

Tags: mysql

eg : field name = User_id 
Value=abc later i want to insert xyz without disturbing abc Value= abc,xyz  i want to insert efg without disturbing abc  then Value= abc,xyz,efg  and so on
i want to seperating each value by using ","(comma). can any one help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL UPDATE append data into column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020867/mysql-update-append-data-into-column)

Comment: Close but not really a duplicate IMHO.

Comment: This is probably a bad idea,

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you could often refer to the value of a column just by using the column name. And to concatenate strings with a separator there's a nifty function called [concat_ws](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) (concat with separator).
In your case the code would look something like

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Value = CONCAT_WS(',', Value, 'cde')
WHERE User_id = 123;
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL **CONCAT_WS()** function is used to join two or more strings with separator. The separator specified in the first argument is added between two strings. The separator itself can be a string. If the separator is NULL the result is NULL.

[Click hear for more information](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat_ws-function.php)