# SQL command to add to end of string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I'd like a bit of help please with an SQL command

I have some text and I need to add and an extension to the end of the string on anything.

I've tried this but it doesn't work the way I want it to:

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1  = '%TEST%' WHERE 'column1' LIKE '%TEST%' + '.exe'
```

as the output I'd like is

```
TEST1.exe
TEST2.exe
TEST3.exe
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I append a string to an existing field in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765631/how-can-i-append-a-string-to-an-existing-field-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `CONCAT` to add to the string, and your `UPDATE` syntax isn't quite right. This should work:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = CONCAT(column1, '.exe')
WHERE column1 LIKE '%TEST%'
```

Comment: looking into the mysql databse its added it outside the [    ] is there anyway to get it inside the [   ]     ["TEST1"].exe

Comment: @DanielPeters can you show me some sample data - the data in your question doesn't have any `[]` around it...

Comment: ["http:\/\/URL1\/1"]

Comment: @DanielPeters I presume you want to end up with `["http://URL1/1.exe"]`? What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: msql 5.7.26 the url displays like that in phpmyadmin i think it would need to end up as 
["http:\/\/URL1\/1.exe"]

Comment: Are all the names in that general form i.e. `["` followed by name followed by `"]`?

Comment: yes ["http:\/\/URL 1\/1"]["http:\/\/URL 2\/2"] also where there are two urls in that column how to i get the .exe to apply to url 1 and not url 2

Comment: @DanielPeters take a look at [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b01694e1ee7bd608229440d331090b9b) I think it should do what you want?