# Mysql append column value

Tags: mysql

I am having the table with the following structure

```
      ----------------------------
       id                  content
      ---------------------------
        1                   abc
        2                   bca
      ---------------------------
```

I want to append the character 'd' with the field 'content' ...
So i want the table structure as follows

```
       ----------------------------
       id                  content
      ---------------------------
        1                   abcd
        2                   bca
      ---------------------------
```

How can i do this..

Comment: You only want to do for a specific row or all the rows .. ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prepend a string to a column value in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680801/how-to-prepend-a-string-to-a-column-value-in-mysql)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761583/appending-data-to-a-mysql-database-field-that-already-has-data-in-it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [**`CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), like so

```
SELECT 
  id,
  CONCAT(content, 'd') content
FROM tablename;
```

You can also specify a `WHERE` clause to determine which rows to update. Something like:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  CONCAT(content, 'd') content
FROM tablename
WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: +1 for quick answer. But this will add `d` to that specific column in all row and OP doesn't mentioned this

Comment: @diEcho I updated my answer. But the question is lack more information about what exactly the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 38):

If you want update the column from the Table then use below Query

```
update table1 set content = concat(content,'d');
```

If you want to select the column concatenation with 'd; the use below Query

```
select id, concat(content,'d') as content from table1;
```

Refer :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/099c8/1