# Insert value into existing value MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I have this table.

```
 ID  Message

 1   Jack went to the park.
 2   Jamie went to the store.
 3   Lucy finished school.
```

How can I mass insert values into the `Message` column without completely overwriting the existing value?

For example

```
 ID  Message

 1   Jack went to the park **at 3pm**.
 2   Jamie went to the store **at 3pm**.
 3   Lucy finished school **at 3pm**.
```

I know I could do this via PHP by retrieving the values and then re-inserting them with the additional value via an array/loop but I wish to do this purely with MySQL via PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: Look up `REPLACE` for MySQL

Comment: possible duplicate of [Appending data to a MySQL database field that already has data in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761583/appending-data-to-a-mysql-database-field-that-already-has-data-in-it)

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE `table`
   SET `Message` = CONCAT(`Message`, " at 3pm")
 WHERE 1;
```