# Append data to a MySQL table but not if it includes "string"

Tags: mysql

I checked this answer [Appending data to a MySQL database field that already has data in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761583/appending-data-to-a-mysql-database-field-that-already-has-data-in-it)

And that tells me how I can append data to a MySQL table, which is great.  But I don't want to do it for certain tables.  For example if it includes a couple of strings.  Is that possible?

Ideally I want to run an SQL query to append the word "course" to my products in WooCommerce.  But I don't want it to add it if the word "bundle" exists.

Comment: You should narrow your question. There are 2 kinds of input check: client-side (done in client's UI) ans server-side (done on the server). Also, it is not obvious what kind of string you want to prohibit - add an example.

Comment: @Oleg thank you so much for your feedback.  I have updated my query, does that help or is there some way I can add more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this SQL query:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET field_name = CONCAT_WS(' ', 'course', field_name) 
WHERE field_name NOT LIKE '%bundle%';
```

This will prefix all records that don't contain the word `bundle` with the word `course`.