# Add text to a field with sql query

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have a field in the mysql database and I would like to insert text in front of all the values in that field.

I would like to add "F21 - "
So the field would be "F21 - product name" instead of "product name"

I need a simple sql query

any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680801/prepending-a-string-to-a-column-value-in-mysql

Comment: That question didn't have any of the search terms I used so I didn't find it. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat). Something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET myfield = CONCAT('f21 -', myfield)
```