# MySQL: How to pre-append text to data in an existing column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a populated MySQL TABLE where I need to pre-append the text "NEW_" for the name field. (Long story, but this is what needs to be done for now.)

I imagine this can be done with an UPDATE but I'm not sure how to add "NEW_" to the start of the 'name' column. I also work in PHP, so I need to do this in PHP where I read each record, extract 'name' field, add this and then do an UPDATE for the record? Or can this all be done in MySQL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680801/prepending-a-string-to-a-column-value-in-mysql

Answer (score 4):

use this query

```
UPDATE table_name set `name` = CONCAT('NEW_',`name`)
```

Comment: Why does name appear as `name` in your example? What is the difference between not using ` surrounding the field name? Thanks!

Comment: @Edward using ` around column_name is important when you have used mysql reserved words as column_name. For example group is reserved word in mysql. If you use only `select group from tbl_tp` It will generate error. But if you use **select ` ``group` `` from tbl_tp**, It will not generate error and query will be executed.

Comment: I see, so it's a way to protect against reserved words without having to memorize what all the reserved words are by just putting it into practice to put ` around fields. Thanks for explaining that!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CONCAT` like this:

```
UPDATE tbl SET name=CONCAT('NEW_',name)
WHERE name NOT LIKE 'NEW\_%';
```

The second line will stop this operating on columns with NEW_ already at the start.

Comment: There is a problem with this. A 'name' field which contained data such as "New Time Bar", doesn't get changed to "NEW_New Time Bar".

Comment: Hmm, yes, forgot that _ is a wildcard character. You'd have to use `NEW\_` to see it as a literal.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it like this:

`UPDATE myTable SET name = CONCAT('NEW_',name);`

As posted before by myself this will not work:

`UPDATE myTable SET name = 'NEW_' + name;`