# mysql - append a value to a mysql field

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I've got the following syntax to update a field called "line1" in a mysql table called "addresses" However, instead of just replacing it, I would like to keep the original value in line1 but add my new value at the end of it with a space.

```
UPDATE addresses SET line1="Road" WHERE id=34
```

Any ideas how this could be done?

Thanks

Comment: almost duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680801/how-to-prepend-a-string-to-a-column-value-in-mysql - it is about prepending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and refer to the current value by the name of the column :

```
UPDATE addresses SET line1=CONCAT(line1,' Road') WHERE id=34
```

or

```
UPDATE addresses SET line1=CONCAT(line1,' ', 'Road') WHERE id=34
```