# How do I prepend string to a field value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, prepend

I have a huge table of products from a specific vendor with a UPC column. I need to differentiate these products' UPCs from other vendors. The current idea is to prepend all of these UPCs with the letter `a`.

```
UPDATE abc_items SET upc = 'a' + upc
```

is basically how I imagine doing something like this, but I know it will not work.

Comment: upc = CONCAT('k',upc)

Comment: Maybe this would be a good time to look at normalizing your database.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly as there is no `WHERE` condition for example, but adding a column / re-thinking your database design would seem a better idea than prefixing values.

Comment: @jeroen | This table contains products from a single vendor. We have many vendors that sell us the same products, with the same UPCs. This solution is so we can differentiate which vendor a specific product came from. Anyways, I'm just a dev :/ ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prepend a string to a column value in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680801/how-to-prepend-a-string-to-a-column-value-in-mysql)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just use the [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function.

> CONCAT(str1,str2,...)
>
> Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments. May
> have one or more arguments. If all arguments are nonbinary strings,
> the result is a nonbinary string. If the arguments include any binary
> strings, the result is a binary string. A numeric argument is
> converted to its equivalent nonbinary string form.

```
UPDATE abc_items SET upc = CONCAT('k', upc)
```